arr all packages needed for a dongle to connect to the internet installed by default in ubuntu 24.04
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 at the moment. My only means of access to the internet on my desktop is via a dongle. However apt-get --autoremove jaml removed needed packages for me to connect to the internet. In particular, it removed libau-dev and software updater. Before I logged off I managed to install enough packages to remove the red icon on the title bar. I saw the full damage when I looked at the logs. Any help would be appreciated ( I am using a computer at a public library to write this)

You have the list of packages from your logs. At the library, you have access to https://packages.ubuntu.com to download those packages onto a USB stick. It's a bit tedious, but it will get you there.
